# ReSharper warning about unused parameter in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, resharper

If I have a function in JavaScript that looks something like

```
function whatever(e, obj){
    //here I do something with obj
}
```

ReSharper tells me "Parameter 'e' is never used". Can I do something to get rid of that warning other than doing something pointless with e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of ReSharper 6.0 01 Mar 2011 Nightly Build this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper normally has some message suppression options you can use to hide the message.

Alternatively you could simply use no parameters if the not needed, in JavaScript the caller doesnt care:

```
function whatever() {

}
```

Comment: well I actually need to use obj so that's not really an option.

Comment: Well then just ignore the message until you implement it. Or go with option 1 in my reply and suppress the message. Hover over the message and it should be one of the options near the bottom of the list

Comment: In the case of event handlers which is where I get this issue (sorry probably should have mentioned that) I wont get around to implementing anything, it's more a question of "I have no need for the event object but it's passed to me anyway". As for suppressing the warning that's definitely an option but unfortunately that takes away all unused parameter warnings which isn't ideal.

Comment: Like I said, javascript doesn't really bother. If you dont have the parameters, the event handler will still fire no problems.

Comment: Of course it will, that was never my question. Thanks for taking the time anyway friend.